# can't getPreferences but it keeps changes (can see in manu layout)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I've made a special preferences layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="pref_sound"
    android:title="@string/pref_sound"
    android:summary="@string/pref_sound_summ"
    android:defaultValue="true" />
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="pref_vibro"
    android:title="@string/pref_vibro"
    android:summary="@string/pref_vibro_summ"
    android:defaultValue="true" />
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="pref_screen"
    android:title="@string/pref_screen"
    android:summary="@string/pref_screen_summ"
    android:defaultValue="true" />
</menu>
```

And an activity for it.

```
package com.actionandresttimer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.cboxpreferenses);
    }
}
```

I can start that preferences activity via menu/settings from the main activity and it works. It stores all changes when I close and start my App again:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //return true;

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    //inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

But when I'm trying to call `getPreferences`, it doesn't work

```
public void getPrefs() {
    // sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    //  sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Prefs);
    sPref = this.getSharedPreferences("com.Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    cBoxSoundStatus = sPref.getBoolean("pref_sound", true);
    cBoxVibroStatus = sPref.getBoolean("pref_vibro", true);
    cBoxScreenStatus = sPref.getBoolean("cpref_screen", true);
}
```

I can only see the default preferences settings. My boolean is set to `true` but in the preferences activity layout they are displayed as `false`

I tried the Android Developer website, but I'm new to Java programming and don't understand how to get any information from the official documentation website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

prefs.getBoolean("pref_sound", true);

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. also thank to the guy ho fixed my post. didnt get how to do it properly.